# Tridion 2009 DWT How to know if a checkbox field is checked?

Tags: 2009, dwt

Does anyone knows how to check from a dreamweaver template if a checkbox field is checked or not?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean checkbox in component Fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's only a checkbox when displayed in the CME. 
Basically it's a field like any other, so you can just check for the actual value.

Something like this should work:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="MyField='MyValue'" -->
...
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.Values(1) != ''" -->
...

<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

above will check if checked